# I get a "Error: write after end" in NodeJS/javascript, what could cause this?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httpserver

So this is the code that runs my http server, it compares a key in a GET request to the keys in a JSON file called "users", shown a little further downwards. If I use the key of one of the first two users listed in this file, it works fine and responds just like I want it to. When I use the key of the third user however, it responds with a 403 error (it runs `the response.writeHead(403);` line. What could cause this? (see these iamges for the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSJKQ.jpg)

```
var httpserver = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  try {
    var key = '';
    if (request.url.indexOf('k=') != -1) {
        key = request.url.substring(request.url.indexOf('k=') + 2);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(users).length; i++) {
      if (users[Object.keys(users)[i]].apikey == key) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        response.write(JSON.stringify(users, null, '\t'));
        response.end();
      } else {
        response.writeHead(403);
        response.end();
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

The "users" JSON file (id's, names and APIkeys obfuscated for obious reasons):

```
{   "user1": {
        "auth": "3",
        "name": "Name1",
        "apikey": "key1"   },
    "user2": {
        "auth": "3",
        "name": "Name2",
        "apikey": "key2"   },
    "user3": {
        "auth": "3",
        "name": "Name3",
        "apikey": "key3"   }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error: write after end
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:625:15)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:620:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (pathtoserver/server.js:42:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:602:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
```

Beware, line 42 char 16 (at Server. (pathtoserver/server.js:42:16)) refers to
`response.write(JSON.stringify(users, null, '\t'));` In the code at the top.

I feel like it has something to do with the loop taking too long before finding the third user, and the connection closing before that. What could this be?

I hope that I provided enough information, and if not, be sure to ask for other things that I could add that'll benefit your aid!

P.S. Please beware that English isn't my mother tongue, and that I'm still in high school, which means that there might be some mistakes written in this text.

Comment: Your code calls `response.end()` *inside the loop*. It will *always* get a "write after end" error.

Comment: Oh man, I'm so stupid that I didn't notice this, thanks! I guess I'm just too tired at the moment, and that I was moving things around without actually thinking about the consequences! I'll continue tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## You are running the loop even after response

You need to exit the loop after you write your response. Otherwise it will continue running and will get more results, and will try to send more response.

The fix is quite easy, just add a return true after `response.end();`, which will make sure the loop exits.

## You are making the loop in a wrong way

You probably wanted to make sure if the url has key, then return the result, otherwise throw 403.

But you used `else` in that loop which means if it cannot find the key on first run, it'll throw 403 and still continue the loop.

Here is a working code.

```
const http = require('http')
const port = process.env.PORT;

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  try {
    var key = '';

    if (request.url.indexOf('k=') !== -1) {
        key = request.url.substring(request.url.indexOf('k=') + 2);
    }

    // Make sure there is a key and it's not empty
    // if it's not empty, then run the loop.
    if(key.length){
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(users).length; i++) {
      if (users[Object.keys(users)[i]].apikey == key) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        response.write(JSON.stringify(users, null, '\t'));
        response.end();
        return; // if a result is found, then exit the loop
      } 
    }  
    }

    // if it's empty, then throw 403
    else {
        response.writeHead("403");
        response.end();
      }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)
server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

I moved the requestHandler to a separate place to keep it a little bit clean.

Hope this helps.